# Why would adding disjunction to OWL EL make it more computationally complex?

Tags: rdf, complexity-theory, owl, ontology, protege

I'm trying to understand why adding disjunction to OWL EL would make the language more computationally complex (eg. why adding 'or' would make satisfiability, consistency, and/or subsumption checking impossible in polynomial time... they're p-time in standard OWL EL)

The OWL EL profile disallows, among other things, disjunction and negation. I'm having trouble understanding why disjunction couldn't be implemented using the existing OWL EL constructs, by creating new classes which contain as subsets the disjuncts of a given class expression.

For example, can the expression (in Manchester syntax):

```
  Class1 and (Class2 or Class3) and (Property1 some (Class3 or Class4))
```

be rewritten as:

```
  Class1 and NewClass1 and (Property1 some NewClass2)

  where Class2 is a subset of NewClass1,
        Class3 is a subset of NewClass1,
        Class3 is a subset of NewClass2,
        Class4 is a subset of NewClass2
```

?

I know that the answer is 'no', but why is it 'no'?

Comment: Perhaps Theorem 7 [here](https://lat.inf.tu-dresden.de/research/papers/2005/BaaderBrandtLutz-IJCAI-05.pdf). Full proof should be [here](https://lat.inf.tu-dresden.de/research/reports/2005/BaaderBrandtLutz-LTCS-05-01.ps.gz).

Comment: Long and complete answers have been provided in the answers below and the other comments. Very short version: Consider the tableau tree. `or` introduces a bifurcation, doubling the amount of work (for an `or` with two operands) required for that branch.

Answer (score 7):

By "rewritten to" I guess you mean that you replace all disjunction expressions `C or D` in the original ontology by named class `C_or_D` and add the axioms:

```
`C subClassOf C_or_D`
`D subClassOf C_or_D`
```

You would have to do this recursively because `C` (respectively `D`) may themselves contain disjunctions. Then you have an ontology with a bit more axioms, a bit more concept names, but with a seemingly very close semantics. However, as you suspect yourself, you are wrong. Consider the following example:

```
A subClass C or D
C subClassOf B
D subClassOf B
```

Using your proposed rewriting, you get:

```
A subClass C_or_D
C subClassOf C_or_D
D subClassOf C_or_D
C subClassOf B
D subClassOf B
```

The first ontology entails `A subClassOf B`, while the second does not.

In general, disjunction is problematic in reasoning, because it leads to alternatives. If you want to, say, check consistency, you have to try to find a possible arrangement of the world for one branch of the alternative, and if failed, find a possible arrangement of the world for the second branch of the alternative. Every disjunction possibly multiplies process time by 2. With *n* disjunctions, you possibly get 2 to the power of *n* possibilities to explore.

It's the same in propositional logic: if you have a conjunctive normal form where no disjunction appear, satisfiability is a stupidly simple problem. When you allow disjunction, it's NP-complete.